# How to get url image from firebase and save it in string?

Tags: android

How I can get a String url from:

```
StorageReference file_path = mStorageReference.child("Posts_images")
    .child(currentUser + ".jpg");
file_path.putFile(pickedImageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            //
            String msg = getString(R.string.imageUploadSuccessfully);
            Toast.makeText(AddPost_Activity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this

```
 .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
            if (downloadUri != null) {
                String photoStringUrl = downloadUri.toString();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the if statement where the task is successul you can get the downloadUrl like this:

```
if (task.isSuccessful()) {

 String msg = getString(R.string.imageUploadSuccessfully);
 Toast.makeText(AddPost_Activity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 file_path.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new 
    OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            String url = uri.toString();
            //do stuff
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Handle any errors
        }
    });

}
```

Documentation for more information [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)

Comment: I use .addOnCompleteListener ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You should use .onSuccess listener or the getDownloadUrl()..